# good practice to change local refs configure for 'git push'

Tags: git

I have an output like this for `git remote show origin`:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://myurl/airflow.git
  Push  URL: https://myurl/airflow.git
  HEAD branch: main
  Remote branches:
    dev  tracked
    main tracked
    prod tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    main merges with remote main
    prod merges with remote prod
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    dev  pushes to dev  (up to date)
    main pushes to main (up to date)
    prod pushes to prod (up to date)
```

I was thinking to change `Local refs configured for 'git push': dev pushes to main` instead of `dev pushes to dev`.

My idea is to push changes in my development only to main and pull changes form main to prod, my production branch.
Is this good practice ? How can I do such thing ?

Comment: No.  Don't you think it would be terribly confusing to have your local `dev` branch map to the remote `main` branch?  That's just a mistake waiting to happen.  What you have is sensible.  Use "pull requests" to get stuff onto the main branch.